$\int_0^{\pi} ((\sin{x})^3+(\cos{x})^3)^n dx$ is rational iff $n$ is odd
Define the integral $$I_n = \int_0^{\pi} ((\sin{x})^3+(\cos{x})^3)^n dx$$ for any natural number $n$. I am trying to show that

$$I_n\text{ is rational } \iff n \text{ is odd}$$

My first idea was to create a recursive relation between $I_n$ and $I_{n-2}$ and use the result that $I_1 = \frac{4}{3}$ is rational and $I_2 = \frac{5}{8}\pi$ is irrational. However, I was not able to make any progress. Running this integral in mathematica 14.0 gives a closed form output in terms of Hypergeom function, but I can't make head or tails of it. Any ideas?

Integrate $\sin^mx$ by recursion, then $\sin^mx\cos^nx$ by recursion, then expand the expression.  You just need 'rational' or '$\pi$ times rational', so minimal calculation.

Take care with the monster generated by Mathematica. Try to evaluate for a given $n$. Indeterminate

Although the question has been answered, here are just some fill in details.
$\sin^3x+\cos^3x=\frac{1}{4}(3\sin x-\sin 3x+\cos 3x+3\cos x)=\frac{1}{4}(3\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})+\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}-3x))=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\left(3\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})+\sin(3(x+\frac{\pi}{4}))\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(6\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})-4\sin^3(x+\frac{\pi}{4}))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(3\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})-2\sin^3(x+\frac{\pi}{4}))$
So, $I_n=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}(3\sin x-2\sin^3x)^n dx$.
Put $K_n=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}\sin^nx dx$, using $\int \sin^nx dx=-\frac{\sin^{n-1}x \cos x}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\int\sin^{n-2}x dx$ we get:
$$K_{n+2}=\begin{cases}
\frac{n+1}{n+2}K_n & \text{$n$ is even, $K_0=\pi$}\\
\frac{2}{(n+2)(\sqrt{2})^{n+2}}+\frac{n+1}{n+2}K_n &\text{$n$ is odd, $K_1=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} $}
\end{cases}$$
It follows inductively that $K_n=q_n\pi$, if $n$ is even and $K_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}q_n$, if $n$ is odd, for some $q_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ .
Hence, $I_n=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n\left[\sum_{k=0}^n(-2)^{n-k}3^k\binom{n}{k}K_{3n-2k}\right]$. Let $C_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-2)^{n-k}3^k\binom{n}{k}q_{3n-2k}$, then $C_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ and
$I_n=\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^nC_n\pi & \text{$n$ is even}\\
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{n+1}C_n & \text{$n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$
The result now follows by noting that $I_n>0$ for even $n$, so the corresponding $C_n>0$.

Really like the inductive approach! +1

Not an answer, but an idea of how to get it.
Consider:
$$
I_n = \int_0^\pi (\sin^3{x} + \cos^3{x})^n dx = \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^\pi \binom{n}{k} \sin^{3k}x \cos^{3(n-k)}xdx
$$
Now we have several facts:

$\displaystyle \int_0^\pi \sin^{3k}x \cos^{3(n-k)}xdx \propto B\left(\frac{3k + 1}{2}, \frac{3(n-k) + 1}{2}\right)$.

For $n = 2m$, we have either zero term, or $C \pi$ term (why?).

For $n = 2m + 1$, we have either zero term, or $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ term (why?).


